# Large images (from file) not loading in Picasso, no obvious error seen

Tags: android, picasso

I'm writing an app which gets a list of the images from the gallery on a device and then shows them in a GridView. In my adapter I have the following code (where the width and height are those of the view it will be placed in):

```
PicassoSingleton.with(mContext).load("file://" + imageUri).resize(getImageWidth(), getImageHeight()).centerInside().placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).error(R.drawable.image_error).into(holder.image);
```

On most devices this works really well. However, on some devices where the photos taken are very large (such as the Samsung Galaxy S5- 16MP) some images do not load, and the error resource is displayed. I do not see any obvious log messages from Picasso debugging, only the following:

```
D/Picasso(20171): Main        errored      [R7]+501ms
```

I presume this is due to memory issues, but I am not sure how to go about fixing these. Is it possible to tell Picasso to compress the images? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue appears to be linked to https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/539

Updating to the latest version of Picasso (here 2.3.3-SNAPSHOT) fixed this